# Listening mouse events with XLib or xcb

Tags: xlib, xcb

Is it possible to listen mouse press and release events in `XLib`/`xcb` and don't eat them, but propogate to other windows? I just need to know that mouse button was pressed or released in some event loop with `XLib` or `xcb` in a separate thread, but don't eat them.

I guess that this is impossible, but I need your prove for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's possible using xinput extension:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xinput.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    xcb_connection_t *conn = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(conn)).data;

    struct
    {
        xcb_input_event_mask_t info;
        xcb_input_xi_event_mask_t mask;
    } input_mask;
    input_mask.info.deviceid = XCB_INPUT_DEVICE_ALL_MASTER;
    input_mask.info.mask_len = 1;
    input_mask.mask = XCB_INPUT_XI_EVENT_MASK_RAW_BUTTON_PRESS | XCB_INPUT_XI_EVENT_MASK_RAW_BUTTON_RELEASE;
    xcb_input_xi_select_events(conn, screen->root, 1, &input_mask.info);

    xcb_flush(conn);

    xcb_generic_event_t *event;
    while ((event = xcb_wait_for_event(conn))) {
        xcb_ge_event_t *generic_event = (xcb_ge_event_t *)event;
        switch (generic_event->event_type) {
            case XCB_INPUT_RAW_BUTTON_PRESS:
            case XCB_INPUT_RAW_BUTTON_RELEASE: {
                xcb_query_pointer_reply_t *reply =
                    xcb_query_pointer_reply(conn, xcb_query_pointer(conn, screen->root), 0);
                printf(
                    "%s x: %d y: %d\n",
                    generic_event->event_type == XCB_INPUT_RAW_BUTTON_PRESS ? "press" : "release",
                    reply->root_x,
                    reply->root_y
                );
                free(reply);
                break;
            }
        }
        free(event);
    }
}
```

```bash
gcc main.c -o click-test `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb xcb-xinput`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer. I found the solution with `X Record Extension library` too.

**`event_monitor.hpp`**

```cpp
#pragma once

// Qt include.
#include <QThread>
#include <QScopedPointer>


//
// EventMonitor
//

struct EventMonitorPrivate;

//! Mosue events monitor.
class EventMonitor final
    :   public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void buttonPress();
    void buttonRelease();

public:
    EventMonitor();
    ~EventMonitor() override;

    void stopListening();

protected:
    void run() override;

private:
    friend struct EventMonitorPrivate;

    Q_DISABLE_COPY( EventMonitor )

    QScopedPointer< EventMonitorPrivate > d;
}; // class EventMonitor
```

**`event_monitor.cpp`**

```cpp
#include "event_monitor.hpp"

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
// Xlib include.
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/record.h>
#include <X11/Xlibint.h>
#endif


//
// EventMonitorPrivate
//

struct EventMonitorPrivate {
    EventMonitorPrivate( EventMonitor * parent )
        :   q( parent )
    {
    }

    EventMonitor * q;

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    Display * display = nullptr;
    Display * display_datalink = nullptr;
    XRecordContext context;
    XRecordRange * range = nullptr;

    static void callback( XPointer ptr, XRecordInterceptData * data );
    void handleRecordEvent( XRecordInterceptData * data );
    bool filterWheelEvent( int detail );
#endif
}; // struct EventMonitorPrivate


#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX

void
EventMonitorPrivate::callback( XPointer ptr, XRecordInterceptData * data )
{
    ((EventMonitorPrivate*) ptr)->handleRecordEvent( data );
}

void
EventMonitorPrivate::handleRecordEvent( XRecordInterceptData * data )
{
    if( data->category == XRecordFromServer )
    {
        xEvent * event = (xEvent *) data->data;

        switch( event->u.u.type )
        {
            case ButtonPress:
            {
                if( filterWheelEvent( event->u.u.detail ) )
                    emit q->buttonPress();
            }
                break;

            case ButtonRelease:
            {
                if( filterWheelEvent( event->u.u.detail ) )
                    emit q->buttonRelease();
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    XRecordFreeData( data );
}

bool
EventMonitorPrivate::filterWheelEvent( int detail )
{
    return !( detail >= 4 && detail <= 7 );
}

#endif // Q_OS_LINUX


//
// EventMonitor
//

EventMonitor::EventMonitor()
    :   d( new EventMonitorPrivate( this ) )
{
}

EventMonitor::~EventMonitor()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    XRecordFreeContext( d->display, d->context );
    XFree( d->range );
    XCloseDisplay( d->display );
    XCloseDisplay( d->display_datalink );
#endif // Q_OS_LINUX
}

void
EventMonitor::stopListening()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    XRecordDisableContext( d->display_datalink, d->context );
    XSync( d->display_datalink, true );
#endif // Q_OS_LINUX
}

void
EventMonitor::run()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    d->display = XOpenDisplay( nullptr );
    if( !d->display ) return;

    XRecordClientSpec clients = XRecordAllClients;
    d->range = XRecordAllocRange();
    if( !d->range ) return;

    memset( d->range, 0, sizeof( XRecordRange ) );
    d->range->device_events.first = ButtonPress;
    d->range->device_events.last  = ButtonRelease;

    d->context = XRecordCreateContext( d->display, 0, &clients, 1, &d->range, 1 );
    if( !d->context ) return;

    XSync( d->display, true );

    d->display_datalink = XOpenDisplay( nullptr );
    if( !d->display_datalink) return;

    XSync( d->display_datalink, true );

    if( !XRecordEnableContext( d->display, d->context, d->callback, (XPointer) d.data() ) )
        return;
#endif // Q_OS_LINUX
}
```